# Can't update products on frontend

Tags: magento2, product, frontend, products

In `Magento 2.1.6`, I edited the product data, such as price, name, description. But in the `frontend` it does not updateon the product listing grid , I already cleaned and flushed the cache, I do not know what can I do

When I export products , in `.csv` attribute `store_view_code` value is empty, or default. I have only 1 store view

What I can do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your Full Page Cache is set to use Varnish, check if your `app/etc/env.php` has `http_cache_hosts` defined correctly. For testing purposes you can switch your Full Page Cache (on your local env, never on production!) to the built-in one, flush all caches and then see what happens.
Also, if your cache is set to use Redis, you can switch it to files (also in `app/etc/env.php`), then flush and see what happens.

You can also try checking if your cron jobs are set properly set: 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

And in case your catalog contains a lot of products, you may want to use this 3rd party extension to fix known indexing issues (although that's most likely not the case):
https://github.com/flancer32/mage2_fix_pr9621

...or just upgrade to the most recent version of Magento 2 and see if the issue is still there.